# Ho do I mutate state on asyncThunk pending status in Redux-Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

There an asyncThunk *putCurrency*. So I want to count it's pending time. Here is how I'm trying to implement it ... (It's in my react-app btw)

```
const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: { currency: { pendingTime: 0 } },
  extraReducers: {
    [putCurrency.pending]: state => {
      setInterval(() => {
        state.currency.pendingTime++
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
})
```

But it gives me a *TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked*. I hope you got the idea, so is there any alternative way to mutate state on pedning status ??? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've created a seperate component that dispatches actions to change state.
Not the actual solution, but it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have three actions dispatched by thunk. You can have separate reducer, or add it into existing one. On `pending` you will capture start time, and on `fulfilled` or `rejected` will calculate new time. It would look something like this:

```js
function start(state) {
  state.start = Date.now();
}

function calculate(state) {
  state.lastTimeToComplete = Date.now() - start;
}

let thunkPerformance = createSlice({
  intialState: {
    start: 0,
    lastTimeToComplete: 0
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [thunk.pending]: start,
    [thunk.fulfilled]: calculate,
    [thunk.rejected]: calculate
  }
})
```

This solution don't cover case if thunk will be  executed more than once. Second will rewrite `start` and first one to finish will calculate `lastTimeToComplete`. But as a start it will work.

Another solution would be  starting  interval inside thunk and dispatcing action, and clearing this interval at the end.